# Mongoose.js no length on promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have the following code:

```
Logger.find({api_key: akey}).exec(function(err, loggers) {
  if(err) {
    res.json(300, {"Error": err});
  } else {
    for(var i=0;i<loggers.length;i++) {
    // Do stuff
    }
  }
});
```

Now this works perfectly fine when I try to query for 1-4000 documents, however, if I now try to query for around 10,000 - 40,000 documents I run into the error saying:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

How does it come that when I try to query for a few documents I can actually access the length property without issues, but once I want to query some more document I run into the error not having a length property? Is it just me or what is wrong?

Sincerly

Comment: console.log the `loggers` variable, and see what type of data it holds. Also check the `err` variable for errors.

Comment: What promise do you see here?

Comment: actually I dont see any promise because I pass a function to exec that gets called when the promise is fullfilled. Works like a charm for ~4000 document queries but not for 5000 - 40000. It throws that error when I query for high amounts of documents, saying that "loggers.length" is undefined, meaning that "loggers" must be undefined. But I still don't know why...